# Apache SSPI authentication

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-server-2008-r2, ntlm

For our Intranet we want to use a apache server that authenticates our users through SSPI.
So, first some specs of the server:

```
Windows Server 2008 R2
Apache 2.4(xampp)
```

In the logfile is now this error:

```
[Wed Dec 09 11:01:34.987431 2015] [authnz_sspi:error] [pid 3068:tid 1900] (OS 87)Falscher Parameter.  : [client ::1:59166] authentication failure for "/": user unknown, reason: cannot generate context
```

httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule authnz_sspi_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so 

<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/ebm">
Options None
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthName "SSPI Protected Place"
AuthType SSPI
SSPIAuth On
SSPIAuthoritative On
SSPIOfferBasic Off
SSPIOmitDomain Off
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

As we are using vhosts too, here's the httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ebm"
  ServerName intranet
  ServerAlias intranet
  ErrorLog logs/intranet-error_log
  TransferLog logs/intranet-access_log
  <Location /htdocs/ebm/ >
   AuthType SSPI
   AuthName "Test Login"
   SSPIAuth On
   SSPIAuthoritative On
   SSPIOfferBasic On
   SSPIOmitDomain Off
   SSPIBasicPreferred On
  </Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Actually sometimes it authenticates the user correctly, but most of the time i get an 401 when trying to connect to the intranet. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like i could fix it..
I just had to disable SSL in the apache config. (we don't use it anyway as it's a local server)